# In Cache Coherency (specifically write-through and write-back), can cache be updated even though it hasn't read from the memory first?

Tags: caching

[There are 3 serial process. In the serial 1, the event is blank, and in write-through and write back only the memory column has X. In serial 2, the event is "P reads X" and, both memory and cache column in write-through and write-back have X. Lastly, in serial 3, the event is "P updates X" and, in write-through, both memory and cache have X'. However, in write-back, only the cach column have X' while the memory column is still X.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D19n.png)
From this image, it shows how write-through and write-back works. But, what if in serial 2, instead of "P reads X", it is "P updates X"? What will happen to the memory and cache?

From what I understand, this is what will happen if the serial 2 is "P updates X"

```
|                          |    Write-Through    |      Write-Back     |
| Serial   |     Event     | Memory   | Cache    | Memory   | Cache    |
| -------- |    --------   | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
|   1      |               |     X    |          |     X    |          |
|   2      |  P updates X  |     X'   |   X'     |     X    |   X'     |
```

But I'm not really sure if it's correct though. I need clarificaiton about this.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think "this is what will happen"?

Comment: Because according to their definition, in write-through, if memory is updated, then the cache is also updated and vice versa. In write-back, only the cache is updated and the only way the memory is updated is when the data is removed from the cache.